# Power Bi DAX wrong average calculations

Tags: powerbi, average

I have a tricky question :) I'm trying to calculated simple arithmetical average between joined tables with specific conditions. I was running DAX studio to see results and notice that its having a extra empty row which affects AVERAGE calculations and gives me wrong number. If I remove relationships between table, columns hasn't any empty rows, but when I joined them on a Many to One relationship on a unique event id then I start to see empty row. Both table have event ID column which is unique. Despered to understand why after joining its created empty row. Any ideas?

I tried to use NOT IS BLANK for all columns and values, but still average calculation picking up hidden empty rows.